# Pyspark couldn't seperate CSV fine while pandas does

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

In pyspark I'm trying to read a CSV file with containing couple of text columns. I have did the same thing with `pandas`'s `chunksize` attribute, and it read it well. However, when I try to do it with the same data, by running SQL with pyspark, it parsed the data in a weird way:

```py
df = spark.read.csv("data_simple.csv", sep=',', header=True, inferSchema=False) 
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
spark.sql("""
SELECT new_category from table
""").show(20)
```

The output is:

```
+--------------------+
|        new_category|
+--------------------+
|    IAB3 -  Business|
|    IAB22 - Shopping|
|      IAB17 - Sports|
| IAB1-7 - Television|
|https://cinpaketi...|
| turgut özal _acc...|
| sulak alan _a3pl...|
|      IAB20 - Travel|
|         ACJumpStart|
| belki eve dönüş ...|
| hardcore ve jung...|
|IAB13 - Personal ...|
|000 sq . ft . sta...|
|        IAB12 - News|
| Posta Kutusu 7:0...|
|    IAB5 - Education|
|             General|
|           Education|
|        fingerstyle |
|               Blogs|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

The expected values was like `IAB3 - Business` etc. But It seems it got values from other columns too.

I'm new to pyspark, am I missing something? Why it parses it like this?

Additionally, some of the columns contains very long text, soemtimes around 20k characters. When I pass `inferSchema` as True, it raises the error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Also, at the end, I just want to group by the table by `new_category` and show the counts. When I do it at the first time, it raises error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.showString.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - 20480
>   Hint: Number of columns processed may have exceeded limit of 20480 columns. Use settings.setMaxColumns(int) to define the maximum number of columns your input can have
>   Ensure your configuration is correct, with delimiters, quotes and escape sequences that match the input format you are trying to parse

When I run it second time immediately after first, it gives this error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o105.showString.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - null

The code for it is:

```py
spark.sql("""
SELECT new_category, COUNT(new_category) counts 
FROM table
GROUP BY new_category
ORDER BY counts DESC
""").show(20)
```

I can provide additional info if you need. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide sample csv?